# How would I make a scrollview size change based on amount of cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, swift3

I am looking to pull all the pending locations from my backend, load them up in a tableView that doesn't scroll, but instead, changes height based on the amount of cells I need, put inside a scroll view.

For instance, here is my hierarchy.

label (50px)
tableView (each cell is 80px) <- should change based on amount of cells
textfield (30px)
button (50px)
mapview (375px)

Everything is 505 px tall, excluding the tableView. I am wanting the tableview to be 80px * amount of cells tall meaning my scrollview changes based on the person's amount of pending locations in their area. How would I do this? I would add code but none of the code I have would help solve this.

I am struggling because

```
tableView.frame.height = 80 * cells.count
```

errors saying height is a get only property.

Comment: Don't do that. Put everything into the table view. The table view can d more than just display a list of the same cells. Add a header to it and put the label in there. Add a footer and put the text field and map in there.

Comment: tableView.frame.size.height = 80 * cells.count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame property is a CGRect which is a struct so you have to change it all together.

```
CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
frame.size.height =  80.0 * cells.count;
self.tableView.frame = frame;
```